# Find an appropriate trigonometric substitution of the form x=f(t) to simplify the integral

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Can someone help me find x=f(t) with these questions?

Number 1:  $$\int x\sqrt{8x^2+32x+29} \, dx $$

and

Number 2:    $$\int {\frac{x}{\sqrt{-7x^2+28x-24}}} \, dx $$

I thought it was $\ x= {\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{8}}}\tan(\theta)+2 $ for #1 and $\ x= {\frac{{2}}{\sqrt{7}}}\tan(\theta)-2 $ for #2.

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Have you tried to complete the square?

Comment: Yes I completed the square too

Answer (score 4):

for your first integral substitute $$\sqrt{8x^2+32x+29}=x\sqrt{8}+t$$
for your second integral Substitute $$\sqrt{-7x^2+28x-24}=\left(x-2-\sqrt{\frac{24}{7}}\right)t$$
it is the so-called Euulerian substitution

Comment: Wouldn't a trig sub be better after some manipulation?

Comment: why should Euler has found this? if a trig substitution works always better?

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution

Comment: And do you find it easier to understand than some manipulation and a trig sub?

Comment: hm i have not said that in some cases the trig Subs works better

Comment: This might really be the way to do it. It looks really messy with trig sub.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use a trigonometric substitution, note that
$$
8x^2+32x+29=\frac{(4x+8)^2-6}{2}
$$
so you can set
$$
4x+8=\sqrt{6}\sec\theta
$$
but the integral will be quite messy.

For the second integral, note that
$$
-7x^2+28x-24=4-7(x^2-4x+4)
$$
so you can set $\sqrt{7}(x-2)=2\sin\theta$. Not the best way, in my opinion.